# How do I push a header alongside part of a container?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

I've got some HTML:

```
<div id="thing">
  <div id="contentheader">
    <h3>Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="contentcontainer">
    <div id="image">
      <img alt="balt" src="imagesrc">
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <p>hegl gegl</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to push the h3 in 'contentheader' down alongside the image in 'contentcontainer' while having the body text sit alongside it. Everything is of variable width save the image.

Perhaps an image will demonstrate better:

[image: Is this possible with CSS?]

As you can see, grey corresponds with 'thing', green with 'contentcontainer' and blue with 'contentheader'.

Editing the HTML would be a major hassle. I also can't make anything other than the image fixed-width.  Is it possible to do it with just CSS? (It'd be awesome to be able to do it with floats and stuff but I don't know if it's doable)

Comment: That looks possible. Can you create a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your current HTML/CSS?

Comment: Sure thing. http://jsfiddle.net/Zaktx/

Comment: If you changed your mark-up, this would be much easier (for example: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zaktx/4/)). Is that possible at all?

Comment: Changing the markup would make this easy. Here's a version that does it somewhat questionably with no HTML changes: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Zaktx/3/. If it's acceptable, let me know and I'll add it as an answer. You can also switch it around and have the header be the thing that's absolutely positioned, but that *will* break if the header can ever be more than one line long.

Comment: ahhhh I see, you've removed the image from document flow and then just pushed the other fields to the side using the box model. That would be perfectly acceptable. Change it to an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thirtydot's answewr in the comments section solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a perfect solution with CSS.  You could use positioning but you would probably run into issues if you had a long title that ran more than one line.

If you're open to using javascript the following non-framework snippet would work.

```
// Add the header inside the container div just before the body
containerDiv = document.getElementById('contentcontainer');
headerDiv = document.getElementById('contentheader');
bodyDiv = document.getElementById('body');
containerDiv.insertBefore(headerDiv, bodyDiv);
```

You could recreate this code as a neater, one-liner using jQuery or another javascript framework.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, heres the Css for a rudimentary setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nkapr/

Ask if you have any questions.

Comment: This is going to be a problem if you need more than a single line though as Joe explained.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the HTML structure, it's not been written really with your goal in mind (which is a bummer!)

If all you're after is pushing the H3 container 'contentheader' down in line with the rest of the stuff inside 'contentcontainer' you could set a negative top margin on 'contentcontainer' to pull it upwards, and then add a positive top margin to the elements in 'contentcontainer' which need to go down (in this case 'image') giving the impression that the h3 section actually sits in with the rest of the content. It's a bit of a hack but it might do the trick if you can't alter the HTML.